# Finding the last element (digit) on every line in a file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading from a text file and I need to find the last element (digit) on each line. I don't understand why this code isn't working as I have tried it on a regular string but it doesn't seem to apply in this case.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
result = 0

for line in f:
    string = str(f.read())
    if string[-1:].isdigit() == True:
        result = int(string[-1:])
    else:
        result = 40

print(result)
f.close()
```

The file `file.txt` only contains the line

```
81 First line32
```

so the code should print out `2` as a result, but I only get `40`, as the first condition never becomes true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you `print(line[-1:])` as the first line in the `for line in f` block?

Comment: I don't get anything, or probably just a bunch of blank spaces as the "Press enter to continue" seems to be positioned a few levels down.

Comment: What 'Press enter to continue'?

Comment: It's in the Visual Studio 2015 compiler for Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an f.read() too many. This is all you need:

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
result = 0

for line in f:
    if line[-1:].isdigit():
        result = int(line[-1:])
    else:
        result = 40

print(result)
f.close()
```

Also the `if string[-1:].isdigit() == True:` can be replaced with `if line[-1:].isdigit():`
You may also want to use `line.strip()` to get rid of new lines, or else the comparison will fail.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
result = 0

for line in f:
    l = line.strip()
    if l[-1:].isdigit():
        result = int(l[-1:])
    else:
        result = 40

print(result)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I even did this before, but actually thought I needed the f.read(). Thanks #FacePalm :)

Answer (score 4):

This line is extraneous:

```
string = str(f.read())
```

You don't need to read from your file, and will actually move the file pointer by doing so, causing all sorts of issues. You're already reading with this:

```
for line in f:
```

Thus, what you want is:

```
for line in f:
    if line[-1:].isdigit() == True:
        result = int(line[-1:])
    else:
        result = 40
```

This is [explained in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last character in the line is the end-of-line character.  Use `.strip()` to remove it (it will also remove extra spaces).

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    lastchar = line.strip()[-1]
    if lastchar.isdigit():
      result = int(lastchar)  
    else:
      result = 40        
    print(result)
```

This prints `2` as you requested in your question with the one-line file.

```
81 First line32
```

It will also work for multiple lines, printing the result for each line.